# Can you connect to a Socket.IO from a C++ program?

Tags: c++, html, websocket, socket.io

We have a student project where my team-mate has to connect to me via a socket.  Im running a HTML5 web page and separately from that Im creating a Socket.IO server.  He is running a C++ program in which he scans RFIDs which he has to send to my webpage via the socket. We are struggling to make a connection from his side.  Is there a way for him to connect to my websocket in C++ ?

Im copying all his code without the includes (as Im no c++ programmer)

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
        array<System::String ^>^ dataArray = gcnew array<System::String ^>(51);
        Socket^ aarsServer = gcnew Socket(AddressFamily::InterNetwork, SocketType::Stream, ProtocolType::Tcp);
        array<unsigned char>^ MSG = gcnew array<unsigned char>(1024);
        int a;
        String ^dataAux;// ^dataSend;

        SerialPort^ arduino;
        arduino = gcnew SerialPort("COM4", 2400);
        arduino->ReadTimeout = 1000;

        for(int b=0;b<50;b++)
                dataArray[b]="1234569877";

        while(1)
        {    
                a=0;
                try{
/*  //LEITURA COM TIMEOUT
                arduino->Open();
                dataAux="";
                arduino->DiscardOutBuffer();
                dataAux = arduino->ReadLine();
                arduino->Close();

*/ 
                ////////BLOKO GRANDE//////////////////////      
                if(dataAux!="")
                        {
                                while(a<50)
                                        {
                                                //PROCURAR ESPACO FREE E BUFFERIZR
                                                if(dataArray[a]=="")
                                                        break;
                                                        a++;
                                        }
                                dataArray[a]=dataAux;


            try{
                        //TENTAR ESTABELER, ENVIAR EM REALTIME E LIMPAR O BUFFER
                IPEndPoint^ iped = gcnew IPEndPoint(IPAddress::Parse("192.168.10.2"), 8765);//Server IP
        aarsServer->Connect(iped);
                 //int rcv = aarsServer->Receive(MSG);
                //dataSend="1, " + dataAux + ", 155.238.44.55";
                MSG = Encoding::ASCII->GetBytes("1," + dataArray[a] + ",192.168.10.1");//device IP
                aarsServer->Send(MSG, MSG->Length, SocketFlags::None);
                aarsServer->Shutdown(SocketShutdown::Both);
                aarsServer->Close();
                dataArray[a]="";
                }

                catch (SocketException^ BB)
    {
        Console::WriteLine("Connection Failed with error: {0}", BB->Message);

    }
        ////////BLOKO GRANDE//////////////////////  ///////////////////////////
                }
                }

                catch (TimeoutException ^AA)
                {
                arduino->Close();

                }
                ////////BLOKO PEKENO//////////////////////      

            try{
                        //TENTAR ESTABELER, ENVIAR EM OFFLINE TUDO E LIMPAR O BUFFER
                IPEndPoint^ iped = gcnew IPEndPoint(IPAddress::Parse("192.168.10.2"), 8765);//Server IP
        aarsServer->Connect(iped);
                 //int rcv = aarsServer->Receive(MSG);
                //dataSend="1, " + dataAux + ", 155.238.44.55";
                for(int c=0; c<50; c++)
                {
                        if(dataArray[c]!="")
                        {
                                MSG = Encoding::ASCII->GetBytes("0," + dataArray[a] + ",192.168.10.1");//device IP
                                aarsServer->Send(MSG, MSG->Length, SocketFlags::None);
                                dataArray[c]="";
                        }
                }
                aarsServer->Shutdown(SocketShutdown::Both);
                aarsServer->Close();

                }

                catch (SocketException^ BB)
    {
        Console::WriteLine("Connection Failed with error: {0}", BB->Message);

    }
        ////////BLOKO PEKENO//////////////////////  ///////////////////////////



        }
}
```

Comment: Of course connecting to a socket in C++ is possible. You need to show what you've tried so far, so you can get help with it.

Comment: As @john says, its absolutely possible, socket connections dont typically depend on the language, since they typically boil down to either TCP or UDP connections.

Comment: Ok got it now...  Im no C++ programmer, so Im just dumping all his code...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use WebSockets in C++ then you should consider using a C++ WebSocket Library. There is a list of them on this Wikipedia [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WebSocket_implementations).

I have previously used [libwebsockets](http://git.warmcat.com/cgi-bin/cgit/libwebsockets) to connect a HTML 5 application to a C++ application. The library comes with sample client and server code [here](http://git.warmcat.com/cgi-bin/cgit/libwebsockets/tree/test-server).